# Huge speed difference between class and function approaches to load torch model in python

Tags: python, class, deep-learning, pytorch, model

I have 2 different ways to load a model (in this case, a torch resnet50 model pretrained on places_365, can be found here: https://github.com/CSAILVision/places365, for the code below to work you need the model_path to point to this model). The first one is to create a class and the other to load it with a simple function. The codes are very similar but somehow when I do it with the class it is 3 to 4 times faster than with a simple function. I do not understand why, any ideas? Thanks!
Here is the code (python 3.8):
with the class:

```
from typing import List, Union
import time
import numpy as np
import torch
import torchvision.models as models
from PIL import Image
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torchvision import transforms as trn

import cv2

class FeatureExtractor:
    """
    A class to convert images to features using our pretrained model.
    """

    def __init__(
            self,
            model_path: str,
    ):
        """
        Loads a pretrained ResNet50 network pretrained on Places365. Since the purpose of the
        Network is to extract image features, the top Dense layer is not included. The output size is 1x2048.

        Args:
            model_path: The path of the model file (`.pth.tar`).

        """
        pretrained_model = models.__dict__['resnet50'](num_classes=365)
        checkpoint = torch.load(model_path, map_location=lambda storage, loc: storage)
        state_dict = {str.replace(k, 'module.', ''): v for k, v in checkpoint['state_dict'].items()}
        pretrained_model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
        res50_conv = torch.nn.Sequential(*list(pretrained_model.children())[:-1])
        res50_conv.eval()
        self.model = res50_conv

    def extract_image_features(
            self,
            img: np.ndarray,
    ) -> np.ndarray:
        """
        Given an image, outputs a vector of size 1x2048 with the deep features of the image.

        Args:
            img: the input image

        Returns:
            the output vector with the features
        """
        t_start = time.time()
        centre_crop = trn.Compose([
            trn.Resize((256, 256)),
            trn.CenterCrop(224),
            trn.ToTensor(),
            trn.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
        ])
        
        img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(img)).convert('RGB')
        preprocessed_img = Variable(centre_crop(img).unsqueeze(0))

        places_features = self.model.forward(preprocessed_img).detach().numpy().flatten()
        t_end = time.time()
        print(t_end-t_start)
        return places_features

#a random image in my computer
image = cv2.imread('/home/michael/Documents/thumbs/.png00001.png')

feature_extractor=FeatureExtractor('/home/michael/Gitlab/backend/packages/izirecord-api-cv/izirecord/cv/models/resnet50_places365.pth.tar')

feature_extractor.extract_image_features(image)
```

and with the function load_feature_extractor defined bellow:

```
from typing import List, Union
import time
import numpy as np
import torch
import torchvision.models as models
from PIL import Image
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torchvision import transforms as trn


def load_feature_extractor(
        model_path: str,
):
    """
    Loads a pretrained ResNet50 network pretrained on Places365. Since the purpose of the
    Network is to extract image features, the top Dense layer is not included. The output size is 1x2048.

    Args:
        model_path: The path of the model file (`.pth.tar`).

    """
    pretrained_model = models.__dict__['resnet50'](num_classes=365)
    checkpoint = torch.load(model_path, map_location=lambda storage, loc: storage)
    state_dict = {str.replace(k, 'module.', ''): v for k, v in checkpoint['state_dict'].items()}
    pretrained_model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
    res50_conv = torch.nn.Sequential(*list(pretrained_model.children())[:-1])
    res50_conv.eval()
    return res50_conv


def extract_image_features(
        img: np.ndarray,
) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Given an image, outputs a vector of size 1x2048 with the deep features of the image.

    Args:
        img: the input image

    Returns:
        the output vector with the features
    """
    t_start = time.time()
    centre_crop = trn.Compose([
        trn.Resize((256, 256)),
        trn.CenterCrop(224),
        trn.ToTensor(),
        trn.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ])
    # TODO Review this suspicious color treatment and numpy → PIL → Torch conversion
    #  when easily numpy → Torch can be handle by trn.ToTensor().
    img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(img)).convert('RGB')
    preprocessed_img = Variable(centre_crop(img).unsqueeze(0))

    # TODO Understand this line:
    places_features = load_feature_extractor(feature_extractor_model_path).forward(
        preprocessed_img).detach().numpy().flatten()
    t_end = time.time()
    print(t_end-t_start)
    return places_features



# a random image in my computer:
image = cv2.imread('/home/michael/Documents/thumbs/.png00001.png')


extract_image_features(image)
```

As I said before, the function extract_image_features is much faster with the class approach on images, but why? :)

I was expecting the 2 approach to have similar computation times. I tried printed the times and I get 3.5x faster computation time for the extract_image_features function when I load the model using the FeatureExtractor class, the output is 0.26150083541870117 sec with the class structure and 0.9230237007141113 sec with the function structure.

Comment: Can you provide the code you used to time both approaches?

Comment: You never call `extract_image_features` anywhere.

Comment: thanks I edited the code to answer you guys comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function-based method, you measure both the time it takes to load the model and the time it takes to compute the result on an input image. However,
in the class-based method, you don't measure the time it takes to load the model.

Comment: You're right! The times get similar if I put the t_start and t_end at the beginning and end of the code! Another question on this tho: this is a part of a much bigger code which is much faster with the class structure than function. The feature extractors are called recursively in loops (I'm working with videos, several frames), is there any chance the function causes retracing and the class does not?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *retracing*, but keep in mind that the function will re-load the model for each invocation which seems extremely wasteful

Comment: Damn you're abosulely right and it would be easy to make it so this doesn't happen, has nothing to do with function vs class! Thank you Yakov (can't upvote cause I don't have enough reputation haha but I'll accept!

Comment: Also, note that it often takes much more time for the first inference of the model when you compare it to the next one. This is because a lot of computation optimization is done during the first inference.